# What do you call the small protusion found in merchant stalls that protect people and goods from the rain?

Tags: word-request

[image: ds]

What do you call the small protrusion found in merchant stalls that protect people and goods from the rain? It's called a roof, but I am talking about the part of the "roof" that's protruding a little bit and might be useful for customers. Is there a word for it?

Comment: The projecting part is an _awning_.